# using storyboardID to detect first launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, nsuserdefaults

Using NSUserDefaults, I'm able to present one view if it is the first launch and then another view if it isn't. My problem is, no matter what, the program thinks its the first launch. My code is as follows (in my AppDelegate.m file):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen ]bounds]];

    NSString *storyboardID;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    bool hasLaunched = [defaults boolForKey:@"hasLaunched"];

    if (!hasLaunched) {
        storyboardID = @"firstLaunch";
        hasLaunched = YES;
        [defaults synchronize];

    }

    else {
        storyboardID = @"notFirstLaunch";
    }


    UIStoryboard *main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];

    UINavigationController * navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

        self.window.rootViewController = navControl;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I'm creating a nav controller programmatically. Another strange thing is that the first launch view controller (which always shows up) has a transparent nav bar over it. However, when I push to a different view controller (by presenting it), the second view controller doesn't have a nav bar over the top. I'm not sure why this would be the case, considering I'm moving the nav controller over to a new view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the local variable `hasLaunched` to `YES`, but you are not storing this variable in `NSUserDefaults` -

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

bool hasLaunched = [defaults boolForKey:@"hasLaunched"];

if (!hasLaunched) {
    storyboardID = @"firstLaunch";
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLaunched"];
}
else {
    storyboardID = @"notFirstLaunch";
}
```

I don't really understand your second question. I suggest you ask another question and include screen shots of your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. Any idea why the nav bar disappears when I push to a new view controller? The nav bar is also just a transparent block without a standard back button even when it DOES appear on the initial view controller.

Comment: No, as I said, I suggest you ask another question on that.  Have you tried embedding your view controllers in the nav controllers in your storyboard and then you won't need to create the `UINavigationController` yourself? - You will need to two nav controllers in your storyboard, one for each potential initial view controller and the storyboardID will need to be associated with the nav controllers, not the view controllers

Comment: @Paulw11 I'd also recommend calling [defaults synchronize] immediately after setting the value, to ensure it gets saved.

Comment: @olynoise - that isn't necessary. Read the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize